# Mysql query to find the outof stock

Tags: php, mysql, sql, node.js

My Table structure

product table:

```
id model_id status
1  3        SELL_IN
2  3        SELL_OUT
3  1        SELL_OUT
4  1        SELL_OUT
5  3        SELL_IN
6  2        SELL_IN
7  2        SELL_OUT
8  1        SELL_OUT
```

condition should be:

if the `model_id` that has `SELL_OUT` only and no `SELL_IN` status in the table that will be out of stock and i want to get all those models.

status of product will change if product is sellout (as `SELL_OUT`)
what will be the query to find out of stock group by model id
THANK YOU For helps.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

you can use not exists

```
select model_id
from table a
where not exists( select 1 from table b where a.model_id=b.model_id
                                         and status='SELL_IN')
and a.status='SELL_OUT'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select model_id
from t
group by model_id
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'SELL_OUT';
```

Comment: Thank you .. it work well for me .. save my day sir..